# ASP.NET 5 (MVC6) How to seed users

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

How would you seed users? I am following their documents [here](https://readthedocs.com/projects/aspnet-mvc/downloads/pdf/latest/), but they only show how to seed data that is inserted directly by the ApplicationDbContext.

In the Account controller, the UserManager is created through DI. How would I instantiate a UserManager in the Seed method?

```
 public class SeedData
{
    public static void Initialize(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        var context = serviceProvider.GetService<ApplicationDbContext>();
        var userManager = serviceProvider.GetService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
```

Then in Startup.cs in the Configure method:

```
SeedData.Initialize(app.ApplicationServices);
```

Comment: Also be sure to include using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity in the SeedData class. That's what was throwing me off earlier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the startup.cs in the configure method, you can add the following code to get the UserManager and from there seed the users.

```
var userManager = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
```

Comment: Ah, this is what I was looking for. I must have been super sleepy or something last night.

I updated the question to show a fuller example. Thanks SynerCoder.

Comment: Thanks, wasn't sure where I could get a working usermanager, works great.

Answer (score 0):

You would create a class in the lines of

```
    public class UserSeed
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext _context;
        private UserManager<ApplicationUser> _mgr;

        public UserSeed(ApplicationDbContext context,UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
        {
            _context = context;
            _mgr = users;
        }

        public void UserSeedData()
        {

            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = "foo@foo.com", Email = "foo@foo.com" };

            var result = _mgr.CreateAsync(user,"fooPassword");
......
......

       }
}
```

In the configure method of your startup.cs take userSeed through DI like

```
public async void Configure(...., UserSeed userSeedData)
```

and then inside the method you call

userSeedData.UserSeedData();

**Don't use this code as is**, you would probably want to check if the user already exists before you create it.

*Note: This method will run once every time your application starts.*